# How to Get pass and fail count of API in excel file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, post-processor

I want to print pass and fail count in excel file in jmeter eg:

[Image of the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rJZO.png)

Answer (score 1):

The closest way is:

1. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-gui mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) from the file like:

   ```
   jmeter -g result.jtl -o dashboard
   ```

   it will produce `dashboard` folder in "bin" directory of your JMeter installation where you will be able to find `index.html` file containing the results metrics:

   [image]
3. If it is not enough - there is `statistics.json` file under the `dashboard` folder which looks like:

   ```
   {
     "API2": {
       "transaction": "API2",
       "sampleCount": 25,
       "errorCount": 7,
       "errorPct": 28.0,
       "meanResTime": 291.12000000000006,
       "minResTime": 63.0,
       "maxResTime": 467.0,
       "pct1ResTime": 462.8,
       "pct2ResTime": 466.1,
       "pct3ResTime": 467.0,
       "throughput": 5.869922517022775,
       "receivedKBytesPerSec": 0.6534874677154261,
       "sentKBytesPerSec": 0.0
     },
     "Total": {
       "transaction": "Total",
       "sampleCount": 75,
       "errorCount": 18,
       "errorPct": 24.0,
       "meanResTime": 274.88000000000005,
       "minResTime": 53.0,
       "maxResTime": 494.0,
       "pct1ResTime": 471.4000000000001,
       "pct2ResTime": 486.40000000000003,
       "pct3ResTime": 494.0,
       "throughput": 14.705882352941176,
       "receivedKBytesPerSec": 1.6371783088235294,
       "sentKBytesPerSec": 0.0
     },
     "API3": {
       "transaction": "API3",
       "sampleCount": 25,
       "errorCount": 3,
       "errorPct": 12.0,
       "meanResTime": 260.5999999999999,
       "minResTime": 72.0,
       "maxResTime": 492.0,
       "pct1ResTime": 479.2,
       "pct2ResTime": 488.7,
       "pct3ResTime": 492.0,
       "throughput": 5.847953216374268,
       "receivedKBytesPerSec": 0.6510416666666666,
       "sentKBytesPerSec": 0.0
     },
     "API1": {
       "transaction": "API1",
       "sampleCount": 25,
       "errorCount": 8,
       "errorPct": 32.0,
       "meanResTime": 272.9199999999999,
       "minResTime": 53.0,
       "maxResTime": 494.0,
       "pct1ResTime": 488.20000000000005,
       "pct2ResTime": 493.7,
       "pct3ResTime": 494.0,
       "throughput": 5.534646889528448,
       "receivedKBytesPerSec": 0.6161618607482842,
       "sentKBytesPerSec": 0.0
     }
   }
   ```

   which can be [loaded in Excel and transformed according to your requirements](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-json-file-f65207ab-d957-4bf0-bec3-a08bb53cd4c0)